# How to change the setPage of scrollBar in Qt?

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I create a list of 64 items using scrollAreaWidgetContents on Qt the list is like this:
[image]

I want when I  press the scroll down arrow I got 4 sentences not 5. So for one click down or up of the arrow I skip one sentence.

The code of scrollArea's stylesheet:

```
QFrame{
    border:solid;
}

QScrollBar:vertical {
    width: 15px;
    margin: 30px 0 30px 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    min-height: 30px;
    border: solid ;    
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    border: solid ;
    height: 30px;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    subcontrol-position: up;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    border: solid ;
    height: 30px;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical
{
    image: url(icons/Freccia_Su.png);
}

QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
{
    image: url(icons/Freccia_Giu.png);
}
```

I found the `setPage` in the documentation of `QScrollBar` but I don't understand how to add it? Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about your question as well as what environment you're operating in. For instance, do you have access to the source code of the application, or can you only edit stylesheets? If you can  edit the source of the application, it sounds like you might be looking for setSingleStep(int) which controls how many lines are scrolled using the up/down arrows.

Comment: I use ubuntu 14.04LTS,and I have access to the application.

Comment: ok - could you be a bit clearer about what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to control the number of lines visible in the scroll bar, or how much it moves when you click the up/down arrows?

Comment: when I click I want to move the next line.

Comment: can you show the code of you setting the contents of the scrollarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be expecting too much from QScrollArea. I can't tell from your question how you have set the contents of the QScrollArea, but if you have set a QTextEdit as its widget, then the QScrollArea doesn't know anything about the size of the text, for example. 
You may be better off looking at QListWidget:

```
//assuming a ui with a QListWidget called listWidget

    ui.setupUi(this);
    QStringList items;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      items << "item " + QString::number(i);
    ui.listWidget->insertItems(0, items);
```

This will automatically scroll by one item per click of the scroll bars.

You can create more complicated list entries using QListWidgetItem (see the docs  for QListWidget).

The items can contain widgets themselves, so you can have a custom widget with radiobuttons etc, and use QListWidget::setItemWidget() to set it on each item. The scrolling will take the widget size into account.